# R: modeling on residuals

Tags: r, modeling, glm

I have heard people talk about "modeling on the residuals" when they want to calculate some effect *after* an a-priori model has been made. For example, if they know that two variables, `var_1` and `var_2` are correlated, we first make a model with `var_1` and then model the effect of `var_2` afterwards. My problem is that I've never seen this done in practice.

I'm interested in the following:

1. If I'm using a `glm`, how do I account for the `link function` used?
2. What distribution do I choose when running a second `glm` with `var_2` as explanatory variable?
   I assume this is related to 1.
3. Is this at all related to using the first models prediction as an offset in the second model?

**My attempt**:

```
dt <- data.table(mtcars) # I have a hypothesis that `mpg` is a function of both `cyl` and `wt`
dt[, cyl := as.factor(cyl)]
model <- stats::glm(mpg ~ cyl, family=Gamma(link="log"), data=dt) # I want to model `cyl` first
dt[, pred := stats::predict(model, type="response", newdata=dt)]
dt[, res := mpg - pred]

# will this approach work?
model2_1 <- stats::glm(mpg ~ wt + offset(pred), family=Gamma(link="log"), data=dt)
dt[, pred21 := stats::predict(model2_1, type="response", newdata=dt) ]

# or will this approach work?
model2_2 <- stats::glm(res ~ wt, family=gaussian(), data=dt)
dt[, pred22 := stats::predict(model2_2, type="response", newdata=dt) ]
```

My first suggested approach has convergence issues, but this is how my silly brain would approach this problem. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm wondering whether this question is more likely to find an answer on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), assuming that you write the post with less focus on the code and more on the validity of the approach.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but a similar question was asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47659/residualize-binary-outcome-variable). One commenter (on the accepted answer) adds a note on different types of residuals, which is further covered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1432/what-do-the-residuals-in-a-logistic-regression-mean). I found the answer by Maverick Meerkat particularly useful.

Comment: @slamballais yes, maybe you are right, that would be a good idea. I feel like I've invested so many points, though, I'm commited :D

Comment: perhaps relevant https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368369/regressing-logistic-regression-residuals-on-other-regressors, https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1046/j.1365-2656.2002.00618.x, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244870/how-to-partial-out-a-covariate-in-logistic-regression

Comment: @user20650 thank you for the tips, much appreciated! I think I have to make a crossvalidated post :)

Answer (score 0):

In a sense, an ANCOVA is 'modeling on the residuals'. The model for ANCOVA is *y_i = grand_mean + treatment_i + b * (covariate - covariate_mean_i) + error* for each treatment *i*. The term *(covariate - covariate_mean_i)* can be seen as the residuals of a model with covariate as DV and treatment as IV.

The following regression is equivalent to this ANCOVA:

```r
lm(y ~ treatment * scale(covariate, scale = FALSE))
```

Which applied to the data would look like this:

```r
lm(mpg ~ factor(cyl) * scale(wt, scale = FALSE), data = mtcars)
```

And can be turned into a `glm` similar to the one you use in your example:

```r
glm(mpg ~ factor(cyl) * scale(wt, scale = FALSE), 
    family=Gamma(link="log"), 
    data = mtcars)
```